# What memory access patterns are most efficient for outer-product-type double loops?

Tags: c, performance, memory, blas

What access patterns are most efficient for writing cache-efficient outer-product type code that maximally exploits data data locality?

Consider a block of code for processing all pairs of elements of two arrays such as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
        out[i*M + j] = X[i] binary-op Y[j];
```

This is a standard vector-vector outer product when `binary-op` is scalar multiplication and `X` and `Y` are 1d, but this same pattern is also matrix multiplication when `X` and `Y` are matrices and `binary-op` is a dot product between the `i`th row and `j`-th column of two matrices.

For matrix multiplication, I know optimized BLASs like OpenBLAS and MKL can get **much** higher performance than you get from the double loop style code above, because they process the elements in chunks in such a way as to exploit the CPU cache much more. Unfortunately, OpenBLAS kernels are written in assembly so it's pretty difficult to figure out what's going on.

Are there any good "tricks of the trade" for re-organizing these types of double loops to improve cache performance?

Since each element of `out` is only hit once, we're clearly free to reorder the iterations. The straight linear traversal of `out` is the easiest to write, but I don't think it's the most efficient pattern to execute, since you don't exploit any locality in `X`.

I'm especially interested in the setting where `M` and `N` are large, and the size of each element (`X[i]`, and `Y[j]`) is pretty small (like O(1) bytes), so were talking about something analogous to vector-vector outer product or the multiplication of a tall and skinny matrix by a short and fat matrix (e.g. `N x D` by `D x  M` where `D` is small).

Comment: Shouldn't the conditional in your inner loop be j < M?

Comment: what do you mean by transferrable?  portable?

Comment: Matrix multiplication is a little different; if written properly, it'll be CPU-bound.  Outer product will be memory-bound because you're hitting everything in `out` once.

Comment: Two clarifications:
`out[i*M * j] = X[i] binary-op Y[j];`
you probably mean `out[i*M + j] = X[i] binary-op Y[j];`...?
Also - is it right that you are not looking for paralelization related answers?

Comment: @tmyklebu: You're only accessing `out` once, but you're accessing each element of `Y` `N` times.

Comment: @jakub: fixed and yes.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Yeah.  All I was getting at is that OP shouldn't get his hopes too high.

Comment: @tmyklebu: Not sure about that.  For large M, the naive code is using N times more main-memory bandwidth than necessary.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: It's never using more than twice as much.  You look at elements of `Y` `MN` times.  You write to `MN` elements of `out`.

Answer (score 7):

For large enough `M`, The `Y` vector will exceed the L1 cache size.<sup>*</sup>  Thus on every new outer iteration, you'll be reloading `Y` from main memory (or at least, a slower cache).  In other words, you won't be exploiting temporal locality in `Y`.

You should block up your accesses to `Y`; something like this:

```
for (jj = 0; jj < M; jj += CACHE_SIZE) {        // Iterate over blocks
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = jj; j < (jj + CACHE_SIZE); j++) {   // Iterate within block
            out[i*M + j] = X[i] * Y[j];
        }
    }
}
```

The above doesn't do anything smart with accesses to `X`, but new values are only being accessed `1/CACHE_SIZE` as often, so the impact is probably negligible.

---

<sub>* If everything is small enough to already fit in cache, then you can't do better than what you already have (vectorisation opportunities notwithstanding).</sub>

Comment: Oil made some simplifying and helpful assumptions about your cpu architecture. They are likely correct. So. There is an article by Drepper you should consider reading: [What every programmer should know about memory](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/cpumemory.pdf)

Comment: Of course you don't want the total size of cache, but the size of cache that is associative with the array and also leave enough space for the other data (loop control variables hopefully end up in registers)

Comment: @BenVoigt: To clarify, are you stating that a contiguous section of memory (of size `CACHE_SIZE`) might not map to fit the entire cache, due to set associativity?